# Bulk creation of objects that contains multiple foreign keys in Django

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys, bulkinsert

I have the following models in my DJango app:

```
class Ratings(models.Model):
    field1 = models.ForeignKey(Table1)
    field2 = models.ForeignKey(Table2)
    field3 = models.ForeignKey(Table3)
    field4 = models.ForeignKey(Table4)
    field5 = models.ForeignKey(Table5)

class Values(models.Model):
    grade = models.ForeignKey(Grade)
    rating = models.ForeignKey(Ratings, related_name='ratings')
    value = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I am using the following code to create instances of the Rating table:

```
rating_obj = Ratings(
                    field1_id=id1,
                    field2_id=id2,
                    field3_id=id3,
                    field4_id=id4,
                    field5_id=id5
                )
                rating_obj.save()
```

The above method works but it is way too slow. I have to create around 30 instances of this model. I cant use **bulk_create** as i need the reference of the rating_obj for creating **Values** objects. I have already tried using `raw_sql` for insertion but to no avail.
Can someone suggest a better way for achieving the same.?
P.S. Table1,Table2..etc already have db_index=True in their primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

How about multi-threading using `threading`? This will create the Ratings objects concurrently.

```
import threading

def createRatings(id1, id2, id3, id4, id5):
    return Ratings(
        field1_id=id1,
        field2_id=id2,
        field3_id=id3,
        field4_id=id4,
        field5_id=id5
    ).save()

for ids in idsList:
    threading.Thread(
        target=createRatings,
        args=(
            ids[0],
            ids[1],
            ids[2],
            ids[3],
            ids[4],
            ids[5],
        )
    ).start()
```

Source: https://pymotw.com/2/threading/

Answer (score 0):

@Cole I could not try your answer. What worked for me was :

```
@transaction.atomic
```

at the top of the function. It disables any savepoints in between operations and delays commit to the end of the function. This allows for faster performance,if you have a lot of operations in your view